# Index was outside the bounds of the array in Directory.Exists(String) method

Tags: c#, docker

I use a .net core app in docker (Ububntu 22.04)

i get the following error when i run:
Unhandled exception. System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
at WebServer.FileMethods.ReadConfig() in /src/WebServer/WorkClasses/FileMethods.cs:line 32

this error points to the following code:
line 32

```
if (!Directory.Exists($"{path}Config"))
{
     Directory.CreateDirectory($"{path}Config");
}
```

i tried to point `("/app/Config") instead of ($"{path}Config")`
the result is the same

before reinstalling docker everything worked
the Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() method points to the "/app" path
so the path is correct

Comment: Please could you show the full stack trace, and ideally a [mcve]? It seems very odd to get that error in that place, unless `path` is a property which is throwing the exception when it's being evaluated... (I think it's likely that the stack trace is incorrect in terms of the line number. A complete example would make it much easier to help.)

Comment: Consider using `Path.Combine` instead of simple concatenation (this is not an answer to your issue)

Comment: Do you have some logging nearby? I remember a similar problem due to a concurrency issue with a logging api.

Comment: There is no need to do this check `if(!Directory.Exists())` since `Directory.CreateDirectory` will create a directory at the specified location if it doesn't exist or it will ignore that line otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

this is my mistake and inattention

the error was later in the code, and the log pointed to the first line in the method, which was the line:
if (!Directory.Exists($"{path}Config"))
which I didn't expect
and there was definitely no problem in this line